# Open fzf.vim in split instead of floating window

Tags: vim, neovim, vim-fzf

I've just setup Neovim v0.4.4 with [fzf.vim](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim) ([commit](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim/commit/3348aef05d02828cd8b071ab29476af2029ea3d3)) on a new machine running Manjaro using `sudo pacman -Sy neovim`. Previously (unknown version) the window for FZF has appeared in a split at the bottom but now it appears as a window in the middle of the window as in the screenshot below. How do I configure it to be a split at the bottom instead?

.vimrc:

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')


" PlugInstall and PlugUpdate will clone fzf in ~/.fzf and run install script
Plug 'junegunn/fzf', { 'dir': '~/.fzf', 'do': './install --all' }
Plug 'junegunn/fzf.vim'


" Initialize plugin system
call plug#end()

map <C-F> :Files<CR>
```

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are five kinds of layout for `fzf` according to documentation:

- window (your actual behavior)
- down / up / left / right

For your requested setup, you should add in your `.vimrc` or where you are putting your settings the following line: `let g:fzf_layout = { 'down': '~40%' }` where the `~40%` is the percentage of all your nvim window

Comment: I also found the commit changing the default behavior: https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/commit/c60ed1758315f0d993fbcbf04459944c87e19a48

Comment: Limit height at bottom to 10 lines to get something like `ctrlp`: `let g:fzf_layout = {'down':'10'}`